# Multiple pages in a Qt main window

Tags: qt

I'm new to Qt.

I have a Qt main window which has some information inside.

I can only fill in limited pieces of information in the window. If I have more information, then I should have a "NEXT" tab/button, to go to a next page, within the same window, and a back button.

Also, there is some static information which is to remain the same across all Pages/Tabs.

So, what I wish to ask is..how do I limit the information to let's say..only 10 lines in a page, and if more, it should go to the next page, within the same window, and be able to switch between them? And how to keep the permanent content across all Pages.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: what kind of information? Text? Which widget do you use to show that information? Please be more detailed to get good answer. Just suggestion!

Comment: Uh..I thought of a table first, to manage the rows and columns which i require, but then, how will I manage the table across multiple pages. The information is rows of data, the data is mostly text, with one small coloured rectangle. I suppose each row can be a simple widget(?).

Comment: You could also spread the information on tabs using QTabWidget http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtabwidget.html

Answer (score 2):

Something like a Wizard? See http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/dialogs-classwizard.html

The examples in the Mainwindows section are very good